# the js files to rotate wheel on click in chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-animate

I have been trying for the past few days to find the exact js which makes the wheel in this link to rotate http://www.forbes.com/special-report/2013/philanthropy/top-givers.html

But i'm not able to pinpoint exact js. I added

jquery-1.7.2.min.js ,  jquery.easing.1.3.js,  mustache.js,  jquery.event.drag-2.2.js,  jquery.event.drop-2.2.js, bootsrap.js, roundabout-shapes.js, foresee.js, roundabout.js, top_givers.js, top_givers_data.js, top_givers_template.js, chartbeat.js

but its not working.If anyone could tell me what i'm missing exactly .thankyou !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add the RoundAbout-Plugin for jQuery. You can download it from here: http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/

Here you can find how to use it: http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/#/learn

Basically it's a simple unordered list, on which you have to call the .roundabout() method from this plugin.

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Then in your onload() function:

```
$('ul').roundabout();
```